# Strange routing error in Rails 3.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This irritates me right now, and I've been at it for more than an hour. Maybe one of you has an idea.

I've defined the following routes in routes.rb:

```
resources :ads do
  member do
    post :preview_revision
    get :revise
  end
  collection do
    get :search
    post :preview
  end
end
```

When I run `rake routes`, the preview_revision route is shown correctly:

```
preview_revision_ad POST   /ads/:id/preview_revision(.:format) {:action=>"preview_revision", :controller=>"ads"}
```

However, when I make a POST request to /ads/145/preview_revision, I get the following error:

```
Started POST "/ads/145/preview_revision" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Nov 15 17:45:51 +0100 2010

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/ads/145/preview_revision"):


Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.2ms)
```

- The id (145) exists, yes.
- The action and the controller (action: preview_revision, controller: ads) exist as well.
- All the other routes work perfectly fine
- I've tried restarting the server several times
- I double-checked that it's actually a POST request, that the ID is correct, I really don't know what to do anymore.
- Rails version is 3.0.1

**--- UPDATE ---**

I tried changing the method from POST to PUT, and now it works. Apparently POST routes on member level are not working, or not allowed.

Still, I want to know why. I do know that POST is for creating a member, so a POST request on a member makes no sense, but I didn't find this mentioned anywhere in the Rails guides, and why would `rake routes` display the route, if it doesn't actually work? Is that a bug?

**--- UPDATE 2 ---**

The Rails Routing guide (Edge version) specifically says:

> 2.9.1 Adding Member Routes
>
> To add a member route, just add a
>   member block into the resource block:
>
> ```
> resources :photos
>   do   member do
>     get 'preview'
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> This will recognize /photos/1/preview
>   with GET, and route to the preview
>   action of PhotosController. It will
>   also create the preview_photo_url and
>   preview_photo_path helpers.
>
> Within the block of member routes,
>   each route name specifies the HTTP
>   verb that it will recognize. You can
>   use get, put, **post**, or delete here. If
>   you don’t have multiple member routes,
>   you can also pass :on to a route,
>   eliminating the block [...]

So is the POST on member possible or not possible? Am I missing something? Just to be clear, I don't wanna use it anymore, but still, it bugs me not knowing why it doesn't work.

Comment: This same issue has been driving me insane...any resolution?

Comment: Ran into the same issue - using PUT instead of POST in routes.rb fixed it. Strangely enough, using the path for this route in form_for does use the POST method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do, if you find a bug in actively maintained open-source software, is:

- to submit a bug report to the project's bug tracker isolating the problem as much as possible and with as much detail as possible, and, optionally,
- to include a patch that fixes the bug if you can.

The bug tracker for Rails is at [rails.lighthouseapp.com](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/).

---edit---

The bug tracker for Rails is now at [github.com/rails/rails/issues](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues).

Answer (score 0):

That should be working. I've created a blank app with 3.0.1 and added those routes and it worked.

Have you tried passing the :on param? Something like:

```
resources :ads do
  post :preview_revision, :on => :member
  get :revise, :on => :member

  get :search, :on => :collection
  post :preview, :on => :collection
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I originally tried, and it didn't work either.

Comment: The form which requested the page did not have the hidden input tag with name "_method" in it - maybe that made a difference. It was still a POST request though.